# UIPageViewController does not advance with setViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with two UIViewControllers as children.  I want the user to be able to page between the child views, but I also want to be able to invoke a page automatically.

I've tried every permutation of using setViewControllers that I can, and none of them work to advance the page under program control.

I feel like I must be missing something fundamental here, but I can't see it.

Here's the code.

```
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire
    import SwiftyJSON
    import SVProgressHUD

    class auiPrefsPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

        lazy var auiPrefsControllers: [UIViewController] = {
            return [self.auiPrefsControllerInstance(name: "auiURLPrefs"), self.auiPrefsControllerInstance(name: "auiCredentialsPrefs")]

        }()

        private func auiPrefsControllerInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)

        }

        public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = auiPrefsControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
                return nil

            }

            let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

            guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                return nil

            }

            guard auiPrefsControllers.count > previousIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return auiPrefsControllers[previousIndex]

        }

        public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = auiPrefsControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
                return nil

            }

            let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

            guard nextIndex < auiPrefsControllers.count else {
                return nil

            }

            guard auiPrefsControllers.count > nextIndex else {
                return nil

            }

            return auiPrefsControllers[nextIndex]

        }

        public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
            return auiPrefsControllers.count

        }

        public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
            guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewControllerIndex = auiPrefsControllers.index(of: firstViewController) else {
                return 0
            }

            return firstViewControllerIndex

        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.dataSource = self
            self.delegate = self

            if let vc1 = auiPrefsControllers.first {
                setViewControllers([vc1], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            for view in self.view.subviews {
                if view is UIScrollView {
                    view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
                } else {
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

                }

            }

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        func auiPrefsGoNext() {
            let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "auiCredentialsPrefs")
            setViewControllers([controller], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        public func obtainPrimaryURL(mCode: String) {
            SVProgressHUD.show()
            let rString = "ImaURLthatcantbepublic?aparam=" + mCode

            Alamofire.request(rString).responseJSON { response in
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    let json = JSON(result)
                    if(json["message"] == "ok") {
                        let mURL: String = json["awhURL"].string!
                        let mAPI: String = json["apiURL"].string!

                        // save URLs
                        let sState = auiCoreDataHandler.saveBaseURL(baseURL: mURL)
                        if (!sState) {
                            let sState = auiCoreDataHandler.saveBaseURL(baseURL: "")

                        }

                        self.auiPrefsGoNext()

                    } else {
                        // handle a return error
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                        // some actual error handling here

                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

As can be seen here, the two important bits are the functions obtainPrimaryURL and auiPrefsGoNext.  The first goes out and gets some data and stores it, then it tries to advance to the next page by calling auiPrefsGoNext.  And it's here were I have been wracking my brain and trying approach after approach for days.  The bottom line is it throws no errors, but it doesn't advance to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already created your `auiCredentialsPrefs` controller once (in the the `lazy var`), why do you create it a second (and every) time in `auiPrefsGoNext`?

If this were my code, I'd do:

```
func auiPrefsGoNext() {
    let auiCredentialsPrefsController = auiPrefsControllers[1]
    setViewControllers([auiCredentialsPrefsController], direction: .forward, 
                       animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also, I don't see the benefit of doing a `lazy var` where you're doing it.

Comment: The lazy var is something I see in almost every implementation of UIPageViewController.  I frankly do not understand why it is used here.

As far as using setViewControllers goes, I've tried this in multiple ways, including the above.  It simply doesn't transition between views.  It likewise throws no error.